# Camera follow player with procedural generation

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello i wonder how can i implement camera what follows player in my game. Situation is following - first level is generated - then player is instantiated somewhere in this level then i want camera to follow player to do so - camera needs to have a target that it will follow.. but when game starts camera can not locate player - because level is still generating... so u cant implement click to move mechanic with camera cos camera has no target... what is the best way to make it work? assuming its a 3d top down game where player movement is depend on camera cos its a click to move movement scheme..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a script that is doingthe instantiation of the player, could you not have it call the Camera movement script and give it the player as a target? Then you could just make sure in the Camera script that you must have a target to move.

Answer (score 0):

Impliment a callback to be invoked after your level has generated.

In your camera controller

```
[serialisedFeild] private PlayerInstansiator _playerInstanciator; // assign this 
private Player _player;

void OnEnable()
{
    _playerInstanciator.OnPlayerCreated += AssignPlayer;
}

private void AssignPlayer(Player player)
{
    _player = player;
}
```

In the class which creates the player, something like

```
public event Action<Player> OnPlayerCreated;

private CreatePlayer()
{
    var player = Instanciate(playerPrefab);
    OnPlayerCreated?.Invoke(player);
}
```